# Convert functional component in Class Component in office fabric React js?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, sharepoint, spfx, office-ui-fabric-react

I want to convert the functional component to class component.The code of modal is given below in office fabric class component.I want to convert in class component.I am new in the React and facing some difficulty while conversion functional to class component.

```
import * as React from 'react';
import { Dialog, DialogType, DialogFooter } from 'office-ui-fabric-react/lib/Dialog';
import { PrimaryButton, DefaultButton } from 'office-ui-fabric-react/lib/Button';
import { hiddenContentStyle, mergeStyles } from 'office-ui-fabric-react/lib/Styling';
import { Toggle } from 'office-ui-fabric-react/lib/Toggle';
import { ContextualMenu } from 'office-ui-fabric-react/lib/ContextualMenu';
import { useId, useBoolean } from '@uifabric/react-hooks';

const dialogStyles = { main: { maxWidth: 450 } };
const dragOptions = {
  moveMenuItemText: 'Move',
  closeMenuItemText: 'Close',
  menu: ContextualMenu,
};
const screenReaderOnly = mergeStyles(hiddenContentStyle);
const dialogContentProps = {
  type: DialogType.normal,
  title: 'Missing Subject',
  closeButtonAriaLabel: 'Close',
  subText: 'Do you want to send this message without a subject?',
};

export const DialogBasicExample: React.FunctionComponent = () => {
  const [hideDialog, { toggle: toggleHideDialog }] = useBoolean(true);
  const [isDraggable, { toggle: toggleIsDraggable }] = useBoolean(false);
  const labelId: string = useId('dialogLabel');
  const subTextId: string = useId('subTextLabel');

  const modalProps = React.useMemo(
    () => ({
      titleAriaId: labelId,
      subtitleAriaId: subTextId,
      isBlocking: false,
      styles: dialogStyles,
      dragOptions: isDraggable ? dragOptions : undefined,
    }),
    [isDraggable],
  );

  return (
    <>
      <Toggle label="Is draggable" onChange={toggleIsDraggable} checked={isDraggable} />
      <DefaultButton secondaryText="Opens the Sample Dialog" onClick={toggleHideDialog} text="Open Dialog" />
      <label id={labelId} className={screenReaderOnly}>
        My sample label
      </label>
      <label id={subTextId} className={screenReaderOnly}>
        My sample description
      </label>

      <Dialog
        hidden={hideDialog}
        onDismiss={toggleHideDialog}
        dialogContentProps={dialogContentProps}
        modalProps={modalProps}
      >
        <DialogFooter>
          <PrimaryButton onClick={toggleHideDialog} text="Send" />
          <DefaultButton onClick={toggleHideDialog} text="Don't send" />
        </DialogFooter>
      </Dialog>
    </>
  );
};
```

Comment: What exactly is the challenge you are facing?

Comment: You will not be able to use hooks in a class components, see:
https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-faq.html#:~:text=You%20can't%20use%20Hooks,implementation%20detail%20of%20that%20component.

Comment: Then how can we use this code in class component?

Comment: Has anyone figured out how to use Fluent controls that require an ID in class components?